# Windows 7 "Scan to file" dialog

Tags: windows-7, picasa, scanning

I'm using Windows 7. I have a Brother DCP-7040 scanner and printer, with Brother's ControlCenter3 software installed. I also have Picasa 3.5 installed.

When I press the Scan button on my scanner (plus setting the options and pressing Start on the scanner), a dialog box pops up titled "Brother DCP-7040". The dialog says "Scan To File - Button Press  Select the program to launch for this action: ControlCenter3, Picasa3".

Since I never scan to Picasa I want to disable this dialog and have ControlCenter3 handle all scanner button presses. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: please can you take a screenshot of this and put it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Control Panel, search for 'scanner', then open 'View scanners and cameras'.

Select the scanner, click Properties. On the Events tab, make any necessary adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

I have this same problem and I solve it.
Go to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoplayHandlers\Handlers

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\StillImage\Events\STIProxyEvent\
```

and delete unnecessary entries

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for editing and adding that picture.

As far as I can tell, that popup is part of the brother software and not an internal part of Windows.

Before I go on with any more suggestions, I recommend you take a look inside the brother suite and configuration programs incase they have an option where you can configure the button. Also, click start then look at "Devices and printers", see if you can right click on your scanner and get any additional options.

I have not come across this before as I have not used brother scanners, but I suggest you look in the registry at both HKLM/software/brother and HKCU/software/brother

When you have found the correct place that this software responds to, take a backup first and then delete the Picasa string.

If you cannot find a registry key, look in the program files directory for an configuration file (or `%userprofile%\appdata\local\virtual store\program files`) and edit it accordingly.

If this does not work, as I have taken a number of assumptions here, sorry, you may be out of luck... If all it does is show the dialog box but with one option, sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Canon CanoScan 4400F with the CanoScan Toolbox and Picasa.
I've resolved it by going to Control Panel -> Devices and Printers -> Right click CanoScan -> Scan Properties -> Events -> Select the button events and select the application you want (I've chosen Toolbox for all button events).